# date try parse with dateformat as dmy

Tags: c#

how do i make the following a valid date?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DateTime testResult;
        DateTime.TryParse("31/1/2012", out testResult);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, it is a valid date and your code works.

Comment: Not if the culture is not currently set to en-GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Pass a culture that specifies a DMY date order.

Example:

```
DateTime.TryParse("31/1/2012", new CultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out testResult);
```

Some will suggest using TryParseExact, but that also requires you to specify a culture:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("31/1/2012", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DatetimeStyles.None, out testResult);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("31/1/2012", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't have the same functionality that the OP is looking for.  It looks like they want a TryParse variant, I'm assuming to swallow up bad formatting.  Therefore, I cannot give you an upvote.  I'm sorry

Comment: This only works if day values less than ten have a leading 0, which seems unlikely given that the month value doesn't have a leading 0.

Answer (score 1):

I see, it's a UK date so

```
DateTime testResult;
DateTime.TryParse("31/1/2012", 
    CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out testResult);
```